# php array conversion from two to one dimension

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like following.

```
array(1) {
  ["foo"]=>
  array(2) {
    [1]=>
    string(5) "abcde"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "pqrs"
   }
}
```

now I want to convert it into following

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(5) "abcde"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "pqrs"
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: does the key `foo` differ everytime ?

Comment: How are you getting that array.

Comment: @Viral No the the foo is constant.

uchiha, I am dumping some input array from the form, but need just the part without foo to parse it to another function.

Comment: that's simple `$your_array = $your_array['foo'];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this will do the job:

```
$oneDimensionalArray = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $twoDimensionalArray);
```

Please have a look at [array_merge](http://php.net/array_merge).